# Saving query result

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlCommand com,com2,com3;
        string str;
        con.Open();
        str = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Committee].[dbo].[group] WHERE [Flag] NOT LIKE '1'ORDER BY [GPA] DESC ;";
        com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        string temp;
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            TextBox1.Text = reader["gid"].ToString();
            temp = TextBox1.Text;
            reader.Close();
        }
}
```

I have this code using ASP.NET for web development, this code retrieve a string value. When I store the value on `string temp` I can not use temp again in the code I got an error:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'temp'.

Any one knows why?

Comment: You're only assigning to `temp` if `reader.Read()` it needs to have a value if that if block is not executed. Initialize it to `null` or `string.Empty`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class member variables are initialized but locals are not. That is why you get the compiler error so you should initialize and assign a value to `temp` like this:

```
string temp = string.Empty;
```

Because if your `if` statements evaluate to `false` then the `temp` will be unassigned.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error when you are trying to do something with temp later in the code like this

```
string temp;
if (reader.Read())
{
    TextBox1.Text = reader["gid"].ToString();
    temp = TextBox1.Text;
    reader.Close();
}
//do something with temp - error
```

This is because you string `temp` is not confirmed to have a value. Which means, if the if condition `if (reader.Read())` is not fulfilled, then the string `temp` will remain unassigned.

The cure is to initialize it when you declare, like

```
string temp = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign a value to temp

```
string temp = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying your implementation is wrong or not the best way--but I've always had much more ease of use while using DataTables rather than a reader. Then you can pass the DataTable around and use it anywhere more easily.

I would do something like this instead. Just an alternative implementation that you may find more useful in the future. I realize you are only returning one row here, but regardless--I find this implementation to be a more versatile solution, especially if you would create a data access class that would always return a DataTable after passing it a SQL Statement or Stored Procedure.

I wrote this for your specific scenario, but ideally you would create another method that would call this SQL and return a DataTable to you when called.

Again, I want to emphasize that your way will work with the fixes mentioned above--but you should definitely look into using DataTables in the future, I think you would like it more and find it easier to work with overall. You also would not get the error you are getting now and would always have access to your data withthe DataTable.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand com,com2,com3;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string str;
    str = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Committee].[dbo].[group] WHERE [Flag] NOT LIKE '1'ORDER BY [GPA] DESC ;";
    com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    adapter.SelectCommand = com;

    adapter.Fill(dt);

    TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["gid"].ToString();

}
```